# Why isnt my HTML code rendering after running a php function in another file?

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

I am trying to get an API working with my website. The website uses a mix of HTML and PHP. This makes use of bootstrap for layout. I have 3 PHP files creating a database link, querying the database, putting the information in an array, converting it to JSON and passing it to my index. My index is supposed to then sort the data into the bootstrap framework. Currently, when i call the method to get the data, the html stops rendering on index without error.

Gyazo of what the page looks like currently: https://gyazo.com/a090e6327d91187797a825d6dbf77347

I have redacted the sorting code, as the html stops rendering regardless whether its included or not. in the PHP segment of index, it appears that:

```
$jsonData = $read->getData();?>
```

is causing the issue, although i have been unable to figure out the cause, even through the use of a try/catch statement.

The index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>  
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <h3>Name</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <h3>Price</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <h3>Description</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <h3>Image</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    include_once 'API/product/read.php';
    $read = new Read();
    $jsonData = $read->getData();?>

    </div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files     as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The included read.php

```
<?php
class Read{

    public function getData(){
        try
        {
            // required headers
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            // include database and object files
            include_once 'API/config/database.php';
            include_once 'API/objects/product.php';

            // instantiate database and product object
            $database = new Database();
            $db = $database->getConnection();

            // initialize object
            $product = new Product($db);

            // query products
            $stmt = $product->read();
            $num = $stmt->rowCount();

            // check if more than 0 record found
            if($num>0){

                // Passed array array
                $products_arr=array();

                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    // extract row
                    // this will make $row['name'] to
                    // just $name only
                    extract($row);

                    $product_item=array(
                        "id" => $Id,
                        "name" => $Name,
                        "price" => $Price,
                        "description" => html_entity_decode($Description),
                        "imageURL" => $ImageURL,
                    );
                    array_push($products_arr, $product_item);
                }
                return json_encode($products_arr);
            }

            else{
                echo json_encode(
                    array("message" => "No products found.")
                );
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The database.php included in read.php

```
<?php
class Database{

    // specify database credentials
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "webtestdb";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    // get the database connection
    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" .         $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Finally, the product.php also included in read.php

```
<?php
class Product{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "unit21";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $price;
    public $description;
    public $imageURL;

    // constructor with $db as database connection
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    // read products
    function read(){

        // select all query
        $query = "SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    ".$this->table_name
                    ;

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Whats the output of the following sentence $jsonData = $read->getData();

Comment: Currently it doesnt "output" anything, unless im misunderstanding you?  
$read->getData() returns a json_encoded array

Comment: Here is a gyazo of some of the json data, i have a chrome addon that makes it look nicer and more readable 
https://gyazo.com/abac22f03d568d1759922bec8b5df2d0

Comment: Have you tried write echo:
`echo $read->getData();`

Comment: Its not really going to give you want you want but...
https://gyazo.com/7511e33d3be173c3704bcedd2e8513a1

Comment: I know you need to use javascript to create what you want and you should use ajax to get data from API.
So you need to create another php file,
and in javascript:
$.get('url.php', [], function(response){
//
}, 'json');

Comment: As far as im aware, while JSON does have javascript in the name, this should be fully possible to do with php. Id rather fix the issue im having with the current setup rather than changing the entire thing just to code it in JS instead. Assuming i am understanding you correctly.

Comment: `$jsonData = $read->getData();` doesn't output anything to the page. It just assigns a value to a variable. It's not clear what you expected to happen, though. "sort the data into the bootstrap framework" doesn't really make any sense. Presumably you want to display this data on the page in some way? For that you need to write some more code to process the data and create some HTML. BTW there's not much point encoding your data to JSON unless you plan to use ajax. If you want to render it using PHP then keep it as a PHP object, or else you just have to decode it again anyway in order to use it

Comment: P.S. You have included both jQuery (two different versions!) and Bootstrap twice on your page. This is, at best, pointless and, at worst, could cause weird conflict errors. You only need one copy of each library included in your page.

Comment: I have code that sorts the data for displaying. Im a tad new to PHP and JSON, this is part of a class assignment so still messing around. The point im trying to make is that when i have the code sorting all of the data (and yeah, it decodes it) the html stops working. I slowly tested parts of the website to try to figure out where the issue is, and the code ive shown above is as much as i can remove while still having the error. For some reason, when i call     $jsonData = $read->getData(); , my html stops rendering and i get a page full of code rather than the results.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/q1m1GxxJ

If it helps, this is a link to the code with the code to display the information included.

Comment: What do you mean by "a page full of code" exactly? What code? Your PHP? Or do you mean it's displaying an error message or warning? If so then you need to tell us what it is. Sounds like maybe there's a problem in your class somewhere. P.S. Why on earth are you encoding to JSON and then immediately decoding it again afterwards? This is a completely redundant waste of CPU time and slows down your site (not by much, but it does). You should just return the `$products_arr` directly from the readData function instead of encoding it to JSON. Then you don't need json_decode afterwards.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a090e6327d91187797a825d6dbf77347

This is what i mean. The php seems to run fine, but the html no longer renders.

The reason i am encoding and decoding is because its required as part of our learning, although im starting to think ive misunderstood my tutor, so im going to restart and try this all again from scratch.

Comment: If that's the output you get, it seems like your webserver is not understanding that the page is HTML instead of plain text

Comment: Ok, `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");` is telling the web browser that the output content of the _whole page_ is going to be in JSON format instead of HTML. So it's treating it as text, effectively, instead of parsing the HTML. Did your tutor provide you with that bit of the code? If so I think they are intending you to use an ajax solution like Rafael's answer below. But it's a bad idea to put that kind of directive within a class method, it should not be controlling the page-level functionality in that way. Perhaps part of the solution is to remove the headers?

Comment: That line of code came with the API stuff i was testing that i got online. It was the cause of the issues, and the website is now working correctly. Thanks for you help :)

It seems i cant set your comment as the answer, if you want you can put it as an answer and ill set it as answer

Comment: @Illuminite I've added an answer - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

is telling the web browser that the output content of the whole page is going to be in JSON format instead of HTML. So it's treating it as text, effectively, instead of parsing the HTML. This is why you see your HTML code just dumped onto the page instead of being processed by the browser into a usable website.

You would only use this header if the *whole output* of your script is going to be some JSON, with no other content in it - e.g. like the response to an API call, rather than a user-oriented webpage.

You can also remove

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

since this is only needed if you're making an API method which will be called via AJAX from another domain (it enables cross-origin (CORS) requests). It makes no sense in this context and also opens an unnecessary security loophole.

Answer (score 1):

create new file:

```
ajax.php
<?php
    include_once 'API/product/read.php';
    $read = new Read();
    return $read->getData();
?>
```

javascript in index.php:

```
$(function(){
   $.get('ajax.php', {}, function(response) {
    $.each(response, function(i, k) {
        $('.container').append('<div class="product row" data-id="' + k.id + '"><div class="col-3">' + k.name+'</div><div class="col-3">' + k.price + '</div><div class="col-3">' + k.description + '</div><div class="col-3"><img src="' + k.imageURL + '" title="" alt=""></div></div>');
    });
   }, 'json'); 
});
```

And you included 2 times jquery and bootstrap, remove one.

EDIT:

Because you want solution only in PHP:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($read->getData()); 
foreach ($jsonData as $json) { 
    echo '<div class="product row" data-id="' . $json->id . '"><div class="col-3">' . $json->name . '</div><div class="col-3">' . $json->price . '</div><div class="col-3">' . $json->description . '</div><div class="col-3"><img src="' . $json->imageURL . '" title="" alt=""></div></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: This is still changing the language im using to JS, or requiring me to write in both JS and PHP to solve the issue. My tutor has said that this can be completed without the need to use JS.